# Cutting with ffmpeg a video (recorded with Kodi) gives no image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, kodi

I am trying to cut videos I get from a IPTV add-on in Kodi. The original video can be watched with VLC, Mplayer, xine, etc, but after being copied there is no image. According to mediainfo there is a video stream but nothing can be seen. The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test-1.mpeg  -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.mpeg
```

I suppose there is something wrong with the original videos recorded by Kodi, but they give no problem with any player. A short example video is this one:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0WC80aT-4WrSDNENzhxRUxkOXc

The output with the -report option is this one:

```
ffmpeg started on 2017-09-10 at 02:27:38
Report written to "ffmpeg-20170910-022738.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -y -report -i test-1.mpeg -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.mpeg
ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enabl  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'test-1.mpeg'.
Reading option '-scodec' ... matched as option 'scodec' (force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0'.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '00:00:10.000'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '00:00:10.000'.
Reading option 'test-1-cut.mpeg' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url test-1.mpeg.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: test-1.mpeg.
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] stream=0 stream_type=1b pid=65 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] stream=1 stream_type=3 pid=c9 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] stream=2 stream_type=3 pid=ca prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] stream=3 stream_type=6 pid=191 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 14
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Frame num gap 190 185
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Frame num gap 190 186
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Frame num gap 190 187
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Frame num gap 190 188
[h264 @ 0x8296880] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] Increasing reorder buffer to 3
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture 
[h264 @ 0x8296880] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture 
[h264 @ 0x8296880] no picture 
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
[NULL @ 0x8298500] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:4378768 seeks:2 frames:529
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test-1.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:01:21.19, start: 74380.458944, bitrate: 6510 kb/s
  Program 3102 
    Stream #0:0[0x65], 127, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xc9](esp), 204, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:2[0xca](vo), 198, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3[0x191](esp), 0, 1/90000: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url test-1-cut.mpeg.
Applying option scodec (force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 00:00:10.000.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 00:00:10.000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: test-1-cut.mpeg.
Successfully opened the file.
[mpeg @ 0x829a0e0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'test-1-cut.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1(esp), 0, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:2(vo), 0, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 128 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3(esp), 0, 1/90000: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 1 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 1 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 1
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 1
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 5 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 5 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 5
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 5
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 10 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 10 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 10
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 10
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 5 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 5 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 5
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 5
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 1 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 1 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 1
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 1
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 3 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 3 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 3
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 3
frame=  231 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 13 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 13 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 13
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 13
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 0 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 0 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 0
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 0
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 10 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 9 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 9
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 10
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 6 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 6 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 6
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 6
frame=  231 fps=231 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 0 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 0 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 0
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 0
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 2 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 1 got 7
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 1
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 2
[mpegts @ 0x8292960] PES packet size mismatch
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[mpeg @ 0x829a0e0] First SCR: 0 First DTS: 45000
frame=  231 fps=149 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7344kB time=00:00:10.03 bitrate=5995.5kbits/s    
video:6918kB audio:391kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.483494%
Input file #0 (test-1.mpeg):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 2016 packets read (60807549 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 3360 packets read (1935360 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:2 (audio): 3363 packets read (1291096 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:3 (subtitle): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 
  Total: 8739 packets (64034005 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test-1-cut.mpeg):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 231 packets muxed (7083751 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 417 packets muxed (240192 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:2 (audio): 417 packets muxed (160128 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:3 (subtitle): 0 packets muxed (0 bytes); 
  Total: 1065 packets (7484071 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x82f9860] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3672 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x829b1a0] Statistics: 70457008 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Following a suggestion from a comment, I have tried a static build of the last version of ffmpeg. The resulting file again has a video stream but the player cannot play it. The log is the following:

```
ffmpeg started on 2017-09-18 at 00:14:22
Report written to "ffmpeg-20170918-001422.log"
Command line:
./ffmpeg -y -report -i test-1.mpeg -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.mpeg
ffmpeg version N-87286-g6ce4a635ed-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.4.0 (Debian 6.4.0-4) 20170820
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 74.100 / 55. 74.100
  libavcodec     57.105.100 / 57.105.100
  libavformat    57. 82.100 / 57. 82.100
  libavdevice    57.  8.100 / 57.  8.100
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'test-1.mpeg'.
Reading option '-scodec' ... matched as option 'scodec' (force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-c:a' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-map' ... matched as option 'map' (set input stream mapping) with argument '0'.
Reading option '-ss' ... matched as option 'ss' (set the start time offset) with argument '00:00:10.000'.
Reading option '-t' ... matched as option 't' (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument '00:00:10.000'.
Reading option 'test-1-cut.mpeg' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url test-1.mpeg.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: test-1.mpeg.
[NULL @ 0x4e6d900] Opening 'test-1.mpeg' for reading
[file @ 0x4e6e1a0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=50
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] stream=0 stream_type=1b pid=65 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] stream=1 stream_type=3 pid=c9 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] stream=2 stream_type=3 pid=ca prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] stream=3 stream_type=6 pid=191 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:4
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 14
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x4f23c80] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x4f23c80] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x4f23c80] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[AVBSFContext @ 0x4f23c80] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[AVBSFContext @ 0x4f23c80] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Reinit context to 1920x1088, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Frame num gap 190 185
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Frame num gap 190 186
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Frame num gap 190 187
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Frame num gap 190 188
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] Increasing reorder buffer to 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
................. a lot of similar lines .......................
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 2
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 9, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 6, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
.......... a lot of similar lines...........
[h264 @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] start time for stream 3 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:4378768 seeks:2 frames:529
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test-1.mpeg':
  Duration: 00:01:21.19, start: 74380.458944, bitrate: 6510 kb/s
  Program 3102 
    Stream #0:0[0x65], 127, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xc9](esp), 204, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:2[0xca](vo), 198, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3[0x191](esp), 0, 1/90000: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url test-1-cut.mpeg.
Applying option scodec (force subtitle codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option c:a (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument 0.
Applying option ss (set the start time offset) with argument 00:00:10.000.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 00:00:10.000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: test-1-cut.mpeg.
[file @ 0x4eb6020] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
[mpeg @ 0x4ea6560] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'test-1-cut.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.82.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1(esp), 0, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:2(vo), 0, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3(esp), 0, 1/90000: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 3
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 3
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 8 got 14
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] Continuity check failed for pid 100 expected 8 got 14
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
........... a lot of similar lines .............
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mpegts @ 0x4e6d900] PES packet size mismatch
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[NULL @ 0x4e72500] ct_type:0 pic_struct:3
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
No more output streams to write to, finishing.
[mpeg @ 0x4ea6560] First SCR: 0 First DTS: 45000
frame=  231 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7344kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=6019.5kbits/s speed=42.1x    
video:6918kB audio:391kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.483494%
Input file #0 (test-1.mpeg):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 2016 packets read (60807549 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 3360 packets read (1935360 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:2 (audio): 3363 packets read (1291096 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:3 (subtitle): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 
  Total: 8739 packets (64034005 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test-1-cut.mpeg):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 231 packets muxed (7083751 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 417 packets muxed (240192 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:2 (audio): 417 packets muxed (160128 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:3 (subtitle): 0 packets muxed (0 bytes); 
  Total: 1065 packets (7484071 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x4ef6300] Statistics: 0 seeks, 3672 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x4e6e040] Statistics: 70457008 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

Comment: To ensure this question survives the future breakage of those file locker links, are you able to illustrate the problem using movie snapshots (e.g. a 4x4 grid of stills)? You can then upload them as an image using the official Stack Overflow CDN (imgur.com).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Snapshots (which would be random images from a film) would give no relevant information on the problem. I provided the link for the video in order to anyone could reproduce the problem by using the same file as input. After processing this and other videos, the result cannot be reproduced by any player. However I can add a part of the log file.

Comment: Ok, I was able to copy all the log file, so I have deleted its link. I maintain the link for the input video file. Thanks

Comment: Update your ffmpeg and try again. Get it from http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried the static build at johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg but the result has been the same. The resulting file has a video stream but the player cannot play it. I will update the question with new log.

Comment: `test-1-cut.mpeg` plays for me using VLC 2.2.6 (but there is a 2 second pause before playback continues due to some decoding errors: `[h264 @ 0x7fb0dccb8f80] mmco: unref short failure`).

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been changing the filename of the output file to .ts. 
The command is then:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test-1.mpeg  -scodec copy -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:10.000 test-1-cut.ts
```

The .ts file is playable from initial time.

I do not know why it works. This solution was suggested by the developer of the kodi add-on I was using.

Thanks to all the people that provided feedback.